# How to add a column as header in Julia using pretty tables and data frames

Tags: dataframe, julia, prettytable

I want to add the same header values (from -1 to 1) as the first column in Julia. I have tried pretty tables but I could only add it as row header. In dataframes I want to replace the sequence numbers to the range (from -1 to 1) Pictures and code are attached.

println(DataFrame(AStrings, [:("-1"), :("-3/4") , :("-1/2"), :("-1/4"), :("0"), :("1/4"), :("1/2"), :("3/4"),:("1")]))

pretty_table(AStrings , header = ([-1,-3/4, -1/2, -1/4, 0, [image]1/4, 1/2, 3/4, 1]))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the data is actually more a matrix than a data-frame, and adding another column with a qualitatively different meaning isn't nice. If the idea is just to pretty-print this matrix, perhaps the following is enough:

```
julia> using PrettyTables

julia> data = ["$(rand(0:1000)/1000),$(rand(0:1000)/1000)" for i=1:5,j=1:5]
5×5 Matrix{String}:
 "0.862,0.52"   "0.303,0.367"  "0.747,0.679"  "0.985,0.044"  "0.094,0.463"
 "0.226,0.429"  "0.537,0.598"  "0.625,0.922"  "0.928,0.271"  "0.138,0.162"
 "0.86,0.004"   "0.741,0.861"  "0.747,0.656"  "0.514,0.851"  "0.304,0.555"
 "0.354,0.221"  "0.169,0.824"  "0.431,0.988"  "0.459,0.327"  "0.172,0.614"
 "0.271,0.588"  "0.148,0.942"  "0.842,0.663"  "0.084,0.265"  "0.44,0.818"

julia> names = string.(-1//1:1//2:1//1)
5-element Vector{String}:
 "-1//1"
 "-1//2"
 "0//1"
 "1//2"
 "1//1"

julia> pretty_table(data; header=names, row_names=names)
┌───────┬─────────────┬─────────────┬─────────────┬─────────────┬─────────────┐
│       │       -1//1 │       -1//2 │        0//1 │        1//2 │        1//1 │
├───────┼─────────────┼─────────────┼─────────────┼─────────────┼─────────────┤
│ -1//1 │  0.862,0.52 │ 0.303,0.367 │ 0.747,0.679 │ 0.985,0.044 │ 0.094,0.463 │
│ -1//2 │ 0.226,0.429 │ 0.537,0.598 │ 0.625,0.922 │ 0.928,0.271 │ 0.138,0.162 │
│  0//1 │  0.86,0.004 │ 0.741,0.861 │ 0.747,0.656 │ 0.514,0.851 │ 0.304,0.555 │
│  1//2 │ 0.354,0.221 │ 0.169,0.824 │ 0.431,0.988 │ 0.459,0.327 │ 0.172,0.614 │
│  1//1 │ 0.271,0.588 │ 0.148,0.942 │ 0.842,0.663 │ 0.084,0.265 │  0.44,0.818 │
└───────┴─────────────┴─────────────┴─────────────┴─────────────┴─────────────┘
```

The OP mentioned 9 columns and names advance by 1/4, but it is the same idea (5 columns fit stackoverflow width).

Comment: Oh, that makes a lot of sense. I didn't really understand what they were going for, but if the intent is just to display the data with row headers and column headers, this is the best way.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you're asking to insert the names of the columns as the first column of the DataFrame, is that correct?

If so, you can use `names` to get the column names, and use `insertcols!` to add them as a column:

```
insertcols!(df, 1, :ColNames => names(df))
```

For eg.

```
julia> DataFrame(rand(UInt8, 9, 9), [:("-1"), :("-3/4") , :("-1/2"), :("-1/4"), :("0"), :("1/4"), :("1/2"), :("3/4"),:("1")])
9×9 DataFrame
 Row │ -1     -3/4   -1/2   -1/4   0      1/4    1/2    3/4    1     
     │ UInt8  UInt8  UInt8  UInt8  UInt8  UInt8  UInt8  UInt8  UInt8 
─────┼───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
   1 │    49    110    218    249     10    242     68    235    146
   2 │   134    239    191    166    158    128     74    144    162
   3 │    38      5    222    254     81    216    157     77    145
   4 │   168     12    180    101    239    235    107    147     81
   5 │   201    143     54     77    212    130    176    108    134
   6 │    42      5     27    117     11    162     84    184    118
   7 │   244     86    206     92     44     96    121    241     23
   8 │   196    245    138     59    215     44     68    225     75
   9 │   161     42     55    236     61    107    254    244     34

julia> insertcols!(df, 1, :MyColumnNames => names(df))
9×10 DataFrame
 Row │ MyColumnNames  -1     -3/4   -1/2   -1/4   0      1/4    1/2    3/4    1     
     │ String         UInt8  UInt8  UInt8  UInt8  UInt8  UInt8  UInt8  UInt8  UInt8 
─────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
   1 │ -1                49    110    218    249     10    242     68    235    146
   2 │ -3/4             134    239    191    166    158    128     74    144    162
   3 │ -1/2              38      5    222    254     81    216    157     77    145
   4 │ -1/4             168     12    180    101    239    235    107    147     81
   5 │ 0                201    143     54     77    212    130    176    108    134
   6 │ 1/4               42      5     27    117     11    162     84    184    118
   7 │ 1/2              244     86    206     92     44     96    121    241     23
   8 │ 3/4              196    245    138     59    215     44     68    225     75
   9 │ 1                161     42     55    236     61    107    254    244     34
```